# Get Dynamic Input ID javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an input type check box and load from database and form like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="akses[]" 
id="<?php echo $menu_id;?>" 
value="<?php echo $action_name;?>"> <?php echo $menu_name;?>
```

and my json is

```js
{
"status": 200,
"message": "sukses",
"data": {
    "fullname": "TEST",
    "username": "TEST_USER",
    "position": "24",
    "privileges_status": "based on jabatan",
    "list_menu": [{
        "action_name": "menu1 ",
        "parent_id": 9,
        "menu_id": 15,
        "menu_name": "Menu 1"
    }, {
        "action_name": "menu2",
        "parent_id": 9,
        "menu_id": 16,
        "menu_name": "Menu 2"
    }]
}
```

}

I'm already successfully parsing the id using ajax, but the problem is that I don't know how to to check when id from json is same like the id in input.

If I define manually like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="akses[]" id="15" value=""> Menu 1
```

I can check and automatically check the checkbox

Now I change my input type like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="akses[]" id="menu1" value=""> Menu 1
```

UPDATE: The js like this after implementing suggested answer

```
for (var i = 0; i < res['data']['list_menu'].length; i++) 
 {
   var action_name = res['data']['list_menu'][i]['action_name'];
   var idsFromJSON = new Array();
   idsFromJSON.push(action_name);
   console.log(idsFromJSON);

  $("[name='akses[]']").each(function() {
    this.checked=idsFromJSON.indexOf(this.id)!=-1;
  });
}
```

but didn't work. if I declare array manually like this it works

```
var idsFromJSON=["menu1", "menu2"];
```

Comment: Dynamic IDs are quite a code smell. I'd either leave them off entirely, or use a class instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you give me the example using class?

Comment: <input type="text" class="<?php echo $className; ?>"  value="<?php echo $value; ?>"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this

I would however recommend not to have numeric IDs

```js
var idsFromJSON=["menu15","menu16"];

$("[name='akses[]']").each(function() {
  this.checked=idsFromJSON.indexOf(this.id)!=-1;
});
```

Comment: ok i will change the id using action_name.

i need declare this one manually sir or can loop from json?? 
var idsFromJSON=["menu15","menu16"];

Comment: Sir, if i change the id using action_name (string)

this code : indexOf(this.id)!=-1 still same or change?

and please tell me what mean (this.id) and -1 based on what?
im newbie in javascript, thankyou for help

Comment: You said you can parse the JSON so parse the IDs or action_names into an array and my code will still work

Comment: okay sir, thankyou.

but this value "indexOf(this.id)!=-1;" still same even using action_name or numeric id?

Comment: If the action name is used as id yes. Show your code in the question

Comment: already updated, now i change my input type like this sir [<input type="checkbox" name="akses[]" id="menu1" value="">] Menu 1

the id now using action_name not numeric again.

so this code : indexOf(this.id)!=-1; will change?

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` and add the html (not php) and an example of JSON matching the html - also tell use what the expected outcome. [mcve]

Comment: No it will not change. Try it

Comment: sir im already update the question, im try to save into array but not work, can you tell me whats wrong?

Comment: I’m on my phone. I’ll look in a while

Comment: ok sir already solve my problem. my bad define array inside for and reset all value and make all value not checked.

thanks for your help, education, and everything.

Comment: Yeah, you certainly needs to put `$("[name='akses[]']").each(function() {
    this.checked=idsFromJSON.indexOf(this.id)!=-1;
  });` OUTSIDE the loop that parses the JSON